# Get values spinner in listView(android)

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter

I apologize for my English. I thought a few days how to make a spinner in the ListView, and I was able to do it. But now I do not know how to take data from the spinner. I ask please tell me how to take the data from each spinner in ListView

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvCustomList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**loyout_list_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="10dp">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity**

```
    ListView lvDetail;
    Button btn;
    Context context = MainActivity.this;
    ArrayList myList = new ArrayList();

    String[] nameQuestions = new String[] {
            "question1", "question2", "questions3",
            "questions4", "questions5"
    };

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> listArray = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        lvDetail = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvCustomList);
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendQuestions);

        getDataInList();
        lvDetail.setAdapter(new MyBaseAdapter(context, myList));

        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //how get value all spinners?
            }
        });
    }

    private void getDataInList() {
        for(int i=0;i<4;i++) {
            ListData ld = new ListData();
            ld.setQuestions(nameQuestions[i]);
            myList.add(ld);
        }
    }


}
```

**ListData**

```
public class ListData {

    String questions;

    public String getQuestions() {
        return questions;
    }

    public void setQuestions(String questions) {
        this.questions = questions;
    }


}
```

**MyBaseAdapter**

```
public class MyBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    ListData ld = new ListData();

    ArrayList<ListData> myList = new ArrayList<ListData>();
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    Context context;
    String cardStatusString;

    ArrayList<String> spinnerArray = new ArrayList<String>();


    public MyBaseAdapter(Context context, ArrayList myList) {
        this.myList = myList;
        this.context = context;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this.context);

        spinnerArray.add("1");
        spinnerArray.add("2");
        spinnerArray.add("3");
        spinnerArray.add("4");
        spinnerArray.add("5");
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return myList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public ListData getItem(int position) {
        return myList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        MyViewHolder mViewHolder;

        if(convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_list_item, null);
            mViewHolder = new MyViewHolder();
            convertView.setTag(mViewHolder);
        } else {
            mViewHolder = (MyViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        mViewHolder.sp = spinnerDetails(convertView, R.id.spinner, myList.get(position).getQuestions());
        mViewHolder.nameText = nameDetails(convertView, R.id.nameText, myList.get(position).getQuestions());

        return convertView;
    }


    private TextView nameDetails(View v, int resId, String text) {
        TextView nameText = (TextView) v.findViewById(resId);
        nameText.setText(text);
        return nameText;
    }

    //this is create spinner
    private Spinner spinnerDetails(View v, int resId, String text) {
        Spinner mySpinner = (Spinner) v.findViewById(resId);

        @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
        ArrayAdapter spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(context,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
                    spinnerArray);
        mySpinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);

        return mySpinner;
    }



    private class MyViewHolder {
        Spinner sp;
        TextView nameText;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate over your `ListView` and collect all the selections into a `List` as

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

      List<String> selections = new ArrayList<String>();
      for (int i = 0; i < lvDetail.getChildCount(); i++) {

        // Get row's spinner
        View listItem = lvDetail.getChildAt(i);
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) listItem.findViewById(R.id.spinner);

        // Get selection
        String selection = (String) spinner.getSelectedItem();
        selections.add(selection);
      }

      // process selections
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I would say add a method on the Adapter that returns that value to the activity its in, since there is no other way to get the value otherwise, except with getChildAt as Ravi pointed out. But this may need further tweaking too since for ListViews *the elements that are not visible in the screen are not loaded* (and the spinner value will reset to default), but that depends on what you want this for